# Python: iterating through a list of dictionaries with a for loop

Tags: python

I frequently need to grab `Value1`, `Value2`, and `Value3` from a list of dictionaries like this:

```
bar = [ {'A':[{'B':{'C':'Value1'}}]},
        {'A':[{'B':{'C':'Value2'}}]},
        {'A':[{'B':{'C':'Value3'}}]} ]
```

How can I iterate through this list with a for loop to grab the values `Value1`, `Value2`, and `Value3`? I'm thinking something like:

```
for x in y:
    # Print Something
```

Edit: Sometimes 'A' has a list of more than one dictionary. I could end up with something like. What is a good, efficient way to do this? Beginner here.

```
bar = [ {'A':[{'B':{'C':'Value1'}}]},
    {'A':[{'B':{'C':'Value2'}},{'B':{'C':'Value2b'}}]},
    {'A':[{'B':{'C':'Value3'}},{'B':{'C':'Value3b'}},
    {'B':{'C':'Value3c'}}]} ]
```

Comment: I'd upvote this question just to help him make it better

Comment: What would you want to print from your edited `bar`?

Comment: @ScottHunter I'd like to print all the values for Key 'C'. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for x in bar:
    print(x['A'][0]['B']['C'])
```

That is, for each element `x` in `bar`, grab the 'A' element of that dictionary, then the first item in that list, the `'B'` element of that dictionary, and finally the `'C'` element of *that* dictionary.

The following modification will handle `x['A']` having more than one element:

```
for x in bar:
    for y in x['A']:
        print(y['B']['C']
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Scott. I forgot to put in my original question (now edited) that sometimes 'A' is a list of more than one dictionary.

Comment: Since the question came from a beginner, it might be worth explaining what this doing and why it works as its quite terse.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean `for y in x['A']` on the second line? If I run the code in Python, it says "NameError: name 'a' is not defined".